# Complex submanifolds of Gauduchon manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(X,\omega)$ be an $n$-dimensional Gauduchon manifold, i.e. $\partial \bar{\partial}\omega^{n-1}=0.$ Let $Y$ be a $p$-dimensional complex sub-manifold of  $X$ with the K$\ddot{a}$hler $(1,1)$-form $\omega_Y=\omega|_Y,$where $p<n.$ I want to know whether

$\partial \bar{\partial}\omega_Y^{p-1}=0?$

I appreciate any comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is $\omega_Y$ a Kähler form on $Y$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not express it explicitly. Since $Y$ is a complex submanifold of X, there is an inclusion map $i : Y \hookrightarrow X.$  Set  $\omega_Y:=i^*\omega$.

Comment: Of course. But  I thought a Gauduchon metric was not a Kähler metric. So perhaps you did not mean to call $\omega_Y$ a Kähler form on $Y$?

Comment: Yes,you are right, $\omega_Y$ may not be Kahler.. However, I do not know how to show $\omega_Y$ is Gauduchon, that is how to show $\partial \bar{\partial}\omega_Y^{p-1}=0.$ Can you present the proof of it?Thank you!